# Matplotlib plot becomes blank after tf.image.resize

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, image-processing, tensorflow-datasets

I have some code that I am using with tensorflow datasets.
It's worked fine previously and it may still work. But I don't think so

```
img = parse_image(img_paths[0])
img = tf.image.resize(img, [224, 224])
plt.imshow(img)
```

Just outputs a blank `224x224` canvas.

```
img = parse_image(img_paths[0])
plt.imshow(img)
```

outputs the image correctly.

`img_paths` is a list of strings with pathnames

I have tried:

```
img = parse_image(img_paths[0])
img = tf.image.resize([img], [224, 224])
plt.imshow(img[0])
```

and

```
img = parse_image(img_paths[0])
img = tf.image.resize(img, [224, 224])
plt.imshow(img.numpy())
```

and

```
img = parse_image(img_paths[0])
img = tf.image.resize([img], [224, 224])
plt.imshow(img.numpy()[0])
```

The shape is correct and this code has worked before.
And may still work, I'm thinking I may not use it correctly anymore (been a while since I wrote it).

thanks for any hints or thoughts you can provide? And of course solutions ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "problem" is with Matplotlib. When you resize with Tensorflow, it turns your input to float. Matplotlib accepts two image formats, integers between 0-255 and floats between 0 and 1. If you call `plt.imshow()` on floats of more than 1, it will clip all values and you'll see a white image. It's like you would give Matplotlib only pixels at 1.0 (or 255).

`tf.image.convert_image_dtype` has a `saturate` argument, and its default value makes it that the 0-255 integer range becomes 0-1 float. This is why it "works", because Matplotlib understands that format. After this, the Tensorflow resizing operation keeps it between 0-1 too, so it works.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense to me, the dataset I previously used my code on had normalzied pixel values. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Matplotlib `imshow` definitely does _not_ only accept floats between 0-1.  It normalizes between vmin and vmax, where these are any float64. https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html

Comment: According to your link, that would only be the case for grayscale images, ie without a channels dimension

Answer (score 2):

Huh,

I saw something elsewhere and added this line:

```
img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
```

before resizing and it worked.

This is extremely weird because I didn't need this line before. Maybe due to a version update?

Either way this works:

```
img = parse_image(train_img_paths[0])
img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
img = tf.image.resize(img, [224, 224])
plt.imshow(img)
```